# TextBlock with multiple lines by code on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a string containing some text (note the `\n`),

```
string mText = "Hello\nWorld";
```

When I apply this to a `TextBlock` (generated by code) like this:

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
tb.Foreground = (Brush)App.Current.Resources["PhoneForegroundBrush"];
tb.FontSize = (double)App.Current.Resources["PhoneFontSizeMedium"];
tb.Margin = new Thickness(24, 32, 24, 12);
tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
tb.Text = mText;
```

I don't see the second line. Any ideas?

[UPDATE - Added the usage of this code]

I use this in showing a PopUp on the Screen:

```
// Create PopUp Content:
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
tb.Foreground = (Brush)App.Current.Resources["PhoneForegroundBrush"];
tb.FontSize = (double)App.Current.Resources["PhoneFontSizeMedium"];
tb.Margin = new Thickness(24, 32, 24, 12);
tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;

tb.Text = pMessage;
Grid grid = new Grid();
grid.Background = (Brush)App.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"];
grid.Children.Add(tb);
grid.Width = page.ActualWidth;

// Create PopUp itself:
Popup popup = new Popup();
popup.Child = grid;

// Show PopUp:
SystemTray.BackgroundColor = (Color)App.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"];
popup.IsOpen = true;
```

Comment: Can you see any wrapping at all? If the text is too large? Can you show where are you adding your TextBlock to?

Comment: may be due to height of the control where you are adding the TextBlock is not displaying properly. increase the height of the container & try again.

Comment: I have tried your Code, Its working fine. i have also tried with this: string mText = "Hello\nWorld\n1\n2\n3"; its working

Comment: You tried it successfully with the PopUp?

Comment: Sorry found the error in the variable for the text...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also add the following:

`tb.Text = mText + Environment.NewLine;`

or

`tb.Text = mText + "&#13;" + "&#10;"`

that seems to insert the `<LineBreak/>` into.